# Microserviços + Entidades JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, microsserviços

Tenho dois microserviços REST (projetos separados) respondendo pelas seguintes entidades com mapeamento JPA (@Entity) e cada um com sua própria base de dados.

**Produto(ID e TITULO) e Categoria (ID e TITULO)**

Achei alguns comentários dizendo que o melhor seria replicar as entidades em cada microserviço. Acredito que essa não seja uma boa solução pela duplicidade de código.

Desta forma, como fazer o relacionamento JPA entre as duas entidades (@ManyToMany) sendo que cada uma está em um projeto diferente? Como seria essa arquitetura? Quais as opções?

Comment: Como se faz o relacionamento JPA entre entidades residentes em microservices distintos? **Não se faz**. Nesta pergunta o conceito de microservices com certeza ainda não foi capturado.

Comment: @Caffé eu entendi que por exemplo, em produto eu poderia ter um objeto que armazena a categoria, e em categoria uma lista de objetos de produtos mas sem realizar o mapeamento OneToMany e ManyToOne respectivamente. Desta forma, a integridade deveria ser garantida e caso precisasse acesso da outro serviço, para buscar pore exemplo os produtos por categoria acessaria via REST. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Procurei aqui no SOpt uma resposta sobre Microservices que pudesse ser útil pra você mas não encontrei nada muito decente... Mesmo a tag não está preenchida ainda. Tem umas respostas onde uma parte está legal mas tem um ou outro parágrafo que ferra com partes importantes do conceito. Por ora posso te adiantar: esqueça relacionamento entre entidades em nível de objetos quando estiver falando de microservices. Cada microservice responde por uma capacidade do negócio (um requisito grandão, por assim dizer) e não depende de objetos de outros microservices para poder fazer o seu trabalho.

Comment: Sim, eu acho que entendi. Cada microserviço tem seu comportamento definido, e quanto precisar pode acessar via REST outro serviço para poder completar a sua resposta.

Comment: Isso, e apenas para completar. Se um microservice não tiver qualquer utilidade sem consultar outro microservice, ele não é um microservice de fato porque não é independente e não atende sozinho por uma capacidade de negócio.

Comment: Contribuindo um pouco com a boa resposta do @Caffé.
De fato não se deve pensar no relacionamento propriamente dito entre as entidades quando está se falando de microserviços diferentes.
É possível que em uma reavaliação do cenário entenda-se que produto e categoria devem ficar sob a responsabilidade de um único microserviço, ou até mesmo que para um dos serviços que consulta este só interesse saber a categoria como uma mera descrição por exemplo dentro do proprio produto.
Essa discussão é bem interessante e muitos sugerem que DDD deve ser usado para ajudar a separar contextos dos serviços.